# How to hide the Html tag if it is empty in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4.2

I am having my html is like fallowing,

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
<a name=199><p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">secretHeading</div></p></a>
<a name=333><p><div id=2002 style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">
<div><b>showTitle</b></div>
<div>showContent</div>
</div>
</p>
</a>
<a name=222><p><div class=intro style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">this is text</div></p></a>
```

Then it is displaying like fallowing in the webview

secretHeading 
show title
showContent
this is text

If i am not having empty instead of "showContent" like fallowing

```
<a name=199><p><div  style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">secretHeading</div></p></a>
<a name=333><p><div class=hide id=2002 style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">
<div><b>showTitle</b></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</p>
</a>
<a name=222><p><div class=intro style="padding:0pt,15pt,0pt,15pt;">this is text</div></p></a>
```

if there is no content it needs to hide complete div(name=333) tag .How to write a code for that in objective-c.Can any one share the code thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure I understand your question entirely BUT…

I will assume that you want to assign the class "hide" to a div with an id of 333 (but without any class already set).

From a UIWebView instance you would call the following:

```
NSString *js = @"document.getElementByID('333').className = 'hide'";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

This will execute the JavaScript in you UIWebView; it's the JavaScript that will set the class.

If your needs are different adjust `js` appropriately.

Comment: It's not working dude.otherwise is there any method.to give html without emptystrings.

Comment: Means i will send my html to that method .It needs to check the content inbetween tags.if content is nil then it needs to remove the tag OR hide the tag.